# Spark-Java: How to change Timestamp format of columns in Dataset<Row>?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to map my Timestamp fields in Dataset having values like `2018-08-17T19:58:46.000+0000` to format like `2018-08-17 19:58:46.000`, i.e. **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS**, and some columns to **yyyy-MM-dd**.

For example, I have a dataset **DS1** with columns **id, lastModif, created**:

```
+------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|Id                |lastModif                   |created                     |
+------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
|abc1              |2019-01-14T19:51:55.000+0000|2019-02-07T20:37:53.000+0000|
|AQA2              |2019-02-05T19:26:36.000+0000|2019-02-07T20:40:06.000+0000|
+------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------+
```

From above DS1 I need the `lastModif` column mapped to format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` and `createdTime` column mapped to `yyyy-MM-dd`.
I have similar DS2, DS3 with different column mapping.
I have kept a properties file from which it will fetch the mapping columns as keys and timestamp format as the values.
In the code I am keeping the list of mapping column, and non-mapping columns, and selecting the column:

```
String cols = "Id,created,lastModif";
String[] colArr = cols.split(",");
String mappedCols = "lastModif,created"; //hardcoding as of now.

List<String> mappedColList = Arrays.asList(mappedCols.split(","));
String nonMappedCols = getNonMappingCols(colArr, mappedCols.split(",")).toLowerCase();
List<String> nonMapped = Arrays.asList(nonMappedCols.split(","));

//column-mapping logic
filtered = tempDS.selectExpr(convertListToSeq(nonMapped),unix_timestamp($"lastModif","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").cast("timestamp").as("lastModif"));
filtered.show(false);


public static Seq<String> convertListToSeq(List<String> inputList)
{
    return JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(inputList.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
}

private static String getNonMappingCols(String[] cols, String[] mapped)
{
    String nonMappedCols = "";
    List<String> mappedList = Arrays.asList(mapped);

    for(int i=0; i<cols.length; i++)
    {
        if(!mappedList.contains(cols[i])){
            nonMappedCols += cols[i]+",";               
        }
    }
    nonMappedCols = nonMappedCols.substring(0, nonMappedCols.length()-1);

    return nonMappedCols;
}
```

How do I map the column to the required timestamp format?
And in the line of code `tempDS.selectExpr(convertListToSeq(nonMapped),unix_timestamp($"lastModif","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").cast("timestamp").as("lastModif"));` the `$"lastModif"` is unidentified in Java.
And secondly this way is a static way i.e. hardcoding the mapping column. How do I map the columns from my `List<String> mappedColList` ?

Comment: did you try using `new Column("lastModif")` instead of `$"lastModif"` ?

Comment: Yes. Its giving compilation error "unix_timestamp(Column,String) undefined"

Comment: I tried `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp(tempDS.col("lastModif"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS")`...the compiler error went away, but the my data is in string of type `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS+Z` eg: `2019-02-07T20:37:53.000+0000` and it is getting parsed to null.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all, let's clarify your input data. You mentioned, that you had **Timestamp**, but the output format you listed seems to be just **String** value representing the following format **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ**. Can you confirm this conclusion?
2. In one of your comments you answered that the function `unix_timestamp` returns `null` in your attempt. Looking into the documentation for [unix_timestamp(Column s, String p)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#unix_timestamp-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) we can see that it requires other formats to parse, otherwise it return `null`:

> Parameters:
> **s** - A date, timestamp or string. If a string, the data must be in a format that can be cast to a timestamp, such as **yyyy-MM-dd** or **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS**
> **fmt** - A date time pattern detailing the format of s when s is a string
> Returns:
> A timestamp, or **null** if s was a string that could not be cast to a timestamp or fmt was an invalid format

3. If you input parameters are really String, I'd suggest you the following solution, using Spark SQL functions [to_timestamp(Column s, String fmt)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_timestamp-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) and [date_format(Column dateExpr, String format)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#date_format-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-)

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_timestamp;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.date_format;
....
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .appName("datetime-transformation")
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();

SomeDto someDto = SomeDto.builder()
            .id("abc1")
            .lastModif("2019-01-14T19:51:55.123+02:00")
            .created("2019-01-14T19:51:55.123+02:00")
            .build();

Dataset<Row> ds = spark.createDataset(Collections.singletonList(someDto), Encoders.bean(SomeDto.class)).toDF();

ds.printSchema();
ds.show(false);

Dataset<Row> dfm = ds
            .withColumn("lastModif", to_timestamp(col("lastModif"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"))
            .withColumn("created", date_format(to_timestamp(col("lastModif"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"), "yyyy-MM-dd"));

dfm.printSchema();
dfm.show(false);
```

The output would be:

```
root
 |-- created: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastModif: string (nullable = true)

+-----------------------------+----+-----------------------------+
|created                      |id  |lastModif                    |
+-----------------------------+----+-----------------------------+
|2019-01-14T19:51:55.123+02:00|abc1|2019-01-14T19:51:55.123+02:00|
+-----------------------------+----+-----------------------------+

root
 |-- created: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastModif: timestamp (nullable = true)

+----------+----+-----------------------+
|created   |id  |lastModif              |
+----------+----+-----------------------+
|2019-01-14|abc1|2019-01-14 19:51:55.123|
+----------+----+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made the mapping dynamic:

```
private static Dataset<Row> mapColumns(Properties mappings, String tableNm, String[] colArr, Dataset<Row> tempDS) throws Exception
{
    String mappedCols = "lastmodif,createdDate,endDate";
    Dataset<Row> filtered = null;
    Properties mappingCols = mappings;
    List<String> mapped = Arrays.asList(mappedCols.split(","));

    List<String> colsList = Arrays.asList(colArr);
    ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator itrTmp = colsList.iterator();
    while(itrTmp.hasNext()){
        tempList.add((String)itrTmp.next());
    }

    Iterator itr = mapped.iterator();
    filtered = tempDS.selectExpr(convertListToSeq(colsList));

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String column = itr.next().toString();
        String newCol = column+"_mapped";
        String propertyKey = tableNm+"-"+column;
        String propertyValue = mappingCols.getProperty(propertyKey);

        filtered = filtered.selectExpr(convertListToSeq(colsList))
                .withColumn(newCol, functions.regexp_replace(functions.substring(filtered.col(column), 0, 23),"T", " ")).alias(newCol)
                .drop(filtered.col(column));

        tempList.remove(column);
        tempList.add(newCol);
        colsList = tempList;
    }

    filtered = filtered.selectExpr(convertListToSeq(colsList)); 
    filtered.show(false);
}

public static Seq<String> convertListToSeq(List<String> inputList)
{
    return JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(inputList.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
}
```

But the `String` to `Timestamp` conversion is still pending. As of now I am doing a `substring`, but this logic for all the columns whose data is of type `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.SSSZ` or `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS+0000` etc, but wont work if a column has data of type `yyyy-mm-dd` and the code will break.
I have raised this here: [how to convert string to timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690305/spark-javahow-to-convert-dataset-string-column-of-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-s).