# Spark-Java:How to convert Dataset string column of format "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS+0000" to timestamp with a format?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, timestamp, apache-spark-dataset

I have a Dataset with one column `lastModified` of type string with format "**yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS+0000**" (sample data: `2018-08-17T19:58:46.000+0000`).

I have to add a new column **lastModif_mapped** of type Timestamp by converting the `lastModified`'s value to format "**yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS**".

I tried the code below, but the new column is getting the value `null` in it:

```
Dataset<Row> filtered = null;
filtered = ds1.select(ds1.col("id"),ds1.col("lastmodified"))
                .withColumn("lastModif_mapped", functions.unix_timestamp(ds1.col("lastmodified"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").cast("timestamp")).alias("lastModif_mapped");
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As I have answered in your original question, your input data String field didn't correspond to allowed formats of the [unix_timestamp(Column s, String p)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#unix_timestamp-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-):

> If a string, the data must be in a format that can be cast to a timestamp, such as yyyy-MM-dd or yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS

2. For you case, you need to use [to_timestamp(Column s, String fmt)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_timestamp-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-)

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_timestamp;
...
to_timestamp(ds1.col("lastmodified"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
```

And you don't need to cast explicitly to Timestamp since `to_timestamp` returns already Timestamp.

3. When you use `withColumn("lastModif_mapped",...)` you don't need to add `alias("lastModif_mapped")`, because `withColumn` would create a new column with the provided name.