# How to convert string like "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss+XXXX" to proper date_format in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, timezone-offset

I have a column containing string data like "**2023-03-13T15:18:14+0700**". My final goal is to convert it to a proper date format like "**2023-03-13 15:18:14**". It's best to convert the time to GMT+7 (my location) and then remove the "T" and "+XXXX" part. But if it's too hard or impossible to do, I just need to remove the "T" and "+0700" since most of my data is "+0700".

I read many posts on SOF but had no luck so far. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70394354/why-i-cant-parse-this-date-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-sssz), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60857315/how-to-handle-t-and-z-in-the-date-format-using-pyspark-functions), and the closest one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690305/spark-javahow-to-convert-dataset-string-column-of-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss-s) but no luck since their format is a bit different from mine.

Below is what I got from the latest post:

```
object test extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  val df = Seq("2023-03-13T15:18:14+0700").toDF("time")

  val result = df.select(to_timestamp(col("time"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSXXX").alias("newtime"))
  result.show(truncate = false) // Null

  val result1 = df.select(to_timestamp(col("time"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssXXX").alias("newtime"))
  result1.show(truncate = false) // Null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the right format, the date you have is of type ISO 8601, the right format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`, here's how to use it using `to_timestamp` function:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([["2023-03-13T15:18:14+0700"]], ['time'])
df = df.withColumn("timestamp_utc", to_timestamp("time", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"))
df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()

+------------------------+-------------------+
|time                    |timestamp_utc      |
+------------------------+-------------------+
|2023-03-13T15:18:14+0700|2023-03-13 09:18:14|
+------------------------+-------------------+

root
 |-- time: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp_utc: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `cast()` transformation

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

df = df.withColumn("time", col("time").cast(TimestampType()))

df.show()
```

***Output***

```
+-------------------+
|               time|
+-------------------+
|2023-03-13 08:18:14|
+-------------------+
```

***Schema***

```
root
 |-- time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```